# How to fill an array in parallel in C

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, fill

I need an algorithm that could fill an array(of size n) with the same value, in log(n) time, in parallel. it means that the naive solution would be `for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)` `T[i] = 10` is not enough because it takes `O(n)` time, I need something that could take `O(log(n))`. It is very important that I mention that this is to be done in PARALLEL. I was thinking about a dependancy, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Why would running a task in parallel give you O(log n)? Wouldn't you just get O(n).  n would be smaller by the number of threads you had running simultaneously, but you would still have to fill each and every element individually within each thread. So if you have z threads, you would have O(n/z), which is still linear time. Even if you did some minor loop unrolling you would still need linear time.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by "I was thinking about a dependency"? Do you mean including some kind of library in C? Please be more specific.

Comment: You can't go below linear time since whatever you think of you'd still need to do at least `n` writes to memory.

Comment: Depenency means (in this context) that for example T[i] = T[i-1], this cannot be donne in parallel. This is what I meant. I also found the solution(from a course from MIT): you can do: for (i = 0; i<=n-1;i++) { for(j=pow2(i);j<=pow(i+1);j++) T[j] = T[j - pow2[i]) } AND IT WORKS, and in log(n) time, not n time.

Comment: That looks like *O(n m)* to me.

Comment: @user1324879, why would you want the value of the previous element? You *already* know what value to assign, it is a constant value, `c`.  Why would I waste accessing an array and readability when I can just provide `c`? Your example makes no sense, and as Will pointed out, certainly is *not* `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 3):

There can be multiple ways to confuse yourself as this simple loop

```
for (i = 0; i <= (SIZE / 2); i++) {
    arr[i]=10;
    arr[SIZE-(i+1)]=10;
}
```

Which just makes you feel it is o(n/2) but actually you HAVE to write the value `n` times into the memory. So whichever way you take, you will ultimately be executing the assignment operation `n` times.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to ignore the problems with calling it "O(log n)" that other people have addressed, but would like to instead outline a solution. If you are unfamiliar with [openMP](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/), it is a parallel framework for shared memory computation.

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(T)
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) T[i] = 10;
```

If you have (n / log(n)) processors, then you will still be doing O(n) work, but each processor will only have to do O(n / (n / log(n))) work, or O(log n). This is presumably what you want.

What does this mean for the feasibility of this problem?

```
n     #num procs
4     2
16    4
256   32
65536 4096
```

We can conclude that addressing this problem *might* make sense *only* for arrays of at least sixteen elements and at most 256 elements (you could maybe push it up to 512, even 1024 if this problem was so important to you.)

Moving to a distributed machine is another boat of oats - the communication cost of collecting the array would grossly outweigh the parallelism in initialization, since the number of nodes needed is growing at O(n / log(n)). You would need to do all the computation on the node that created the array.

Comment: I think your answer actually helped to shed light on what the asker was trying to get at. Although I have to agree with you that what the original question wants just isn't feasible.

Answer (score 1):

If you run n threads using n processors, it's still `O(1)* n = O(n)` processors in total (and the performance is going to be terrible).

If you run `t` threads (`t=n/factor`) it may give you better performance depending on how big the array is (A very large array can give good performance if you have more processors). But the point is it's still `O(n)`.

Something can be done in `O(logn)` only if you can skip certain operations based some condition (E.g. Binary search of a sorted array). For initializing n elements in the array, you have to access all n elements. Simply what you desire is not possible.